# Can I use any non-Samsung lenses on a Samsung NX camera, with working autofocus?

Tags: lens, lens-adapter, samsung

I (still) own a Samsung NX (NX300m) camera, sadly there aren't a lot of choices for NX lenses, so instead I try to use other brand lenses.

Is there any possible way I could use for example Canon or Nikon AF lenses and use that autofocus on my NX?

I do have an adapter to put Canon EF lenses on the NX, but you can't use autofocus with that, there are no electrical contacts in it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure you're out of luck. Samsung made one mount adapter, the [ED-MA9NXK](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/708439-REG/Samsung_ED_MA9NXK_ED_MA9NXK_K_Mount_Adapter_for.html), for Pentax K mount — probably because before NX, Samsung made a few Pentax-compatible cameras and lenses. But even that doesn't have autofocus. And, while there are plenty of [third-party manual-only adapters](http://www.kiwifotos.com/product.php?id1=129&id2=130&id3=141), I don't think there are any AF-capable ones — and, since NX is effectively dead, I feel pretty safe in predicting that there won't be any forthcoming. (Samsung has never officially discontinued NX, but [pulled it out of major markets](http://www.techradar.com/news/photography-video-capture/cameras/samsung-quits-uk-camera-market-official-statement-confirms-the-rumors-1310244) and hasn't launched any new products in almost two years.)

So, I'm afraid you have to either enjoy what you have, or move on.